# SQL Select All Where record does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with a number of tables:

```
customer
------
id
name

customer_order
------
order_id
order_cost
customer_id

customer_order_line
------
order_line_id
order_id
order_line_product_id

product
------
product_id
product_name
product_cost
```

What i want to do is select all customers that havent purchased one particular item, for example if i enter "apple" as the variable to enter, I want to return all customers that have not yet purchased an apple.

This is just a scenario.

I have spent a couple of days trying to do this, with things like concatenating all of the products into one field and using `NOT LIKE @searchVariable` but i cannot seem to make it work as it consistently takes into account all records from the `customer_order_line` table.

Could someone point me in the correct direction for this?

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several approaches to this.  Here's one using `not exists`:

```
select *
from customer c
where not exists (
    select 1
    from customer_order co 
        join customer_order_line col on co.order_id = col.order_id
        join product p on p.product_id = p.order_line_product_id
    where c.id = co.customer_id 
        and p.product_name = 'Apple'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, ill try it out now.

Comment: Cheers for your response, once i copied all my table names and fields in it worked perfectly

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way:

```
select co.name, count(*)
from customer_order co 
    left join join customer_order_line col on co.order_id = col.order_id
    left join product p on p.product_id = p.order_line_product_id
where p.product_name = 'Apple'
group by co.name
having count(*) = 0;
```

Comment: I think this is best on performance as it does not involve subqueries

Comment: @Ichirichi - I'm not so sure. The left joins pretty much ensure that the order line and product tables will have full table scans (actual IO, v v slow). Without seeing query plans I really don't know what performance would be, but I suspect sgeddes query would be at least as good as either of the other two options.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the easiest way to answer this is to turn it on its head. How would you find all the customers who *have* ordered an apple. That's fairly simple...

```
SELECT cusomer_id
FROM customer_order co
INNER JOIN customer_order_line col
  ON co.order_id = col.order_id
INNER JOIN product p
  ON col.order_line_product_id = p.product_id
WHERE p.product_name = 'apple'
```

Then, its just a case of finding all customers who are `NOT IN` that list

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT cusomer_id
    FROM customer_order co
    INNER JOIN customer_order_line col
      ON co.order_id = col.order_id
    INNER JOIN product p
      ON col.order_line_product_id = p.product_id
    WHERE p.product_name = 'apple'
)
```

There's a bunch of other (and potentially more efficient) ways to do this, but hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Comment: `NOT IN` can get very slow if there are a lot of records involved. Usually if I see a `NOT IN`, I'll try for a `NOT EXISTS` or a `LEFT OUTER JOIN...WHERE x IS NULL`, though the `NOT EXISTS` appears to be the most performant in most cases.